# Starting all nodes in galera at once

Tags: mariadb, galera

I have a galera cluster of three nodes, If I shut down the the three virtual machines and started them all at once, systemd will automatically start mariadb on each of the virtual machines.

Some times it happens that all of the mariadb instances start at once, and this result of a broken cluster.

Which I have to reinitiate using `galera_new_cluster`

The question is, why does starting all the mariadb instances at once break the cluster ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you start a node, it either starts as the first node in the cluster (initiates a new cluster), or it attempts to connect to an existing nodes using `wsrep_cluster_address`. The behavior depends on the node options.

So, every time when you shut down or lose all nodes and start them again, there is nothing to connect to, and you need to start a *new* cluster. `galera_new_cluster` does that by starting a node with `--wsrep-new-cluster` option which overrides the current value of `wsrep_cluster_address`.

If sometimes it works for you automatically, it most likely means that one of your nodes is permanently configured as the "first node", either via `wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://`, or via `wsrep-new-cluster`. It is a wrong setup in itself. If you lose or shut down *only this node* and have to restart it, it won't join the remaining nodes in the cluster, it will create a new one.

When you start all nodes at once, you create a race condition. If your "first node" comes up first and initializes quickly enough, it will create a new cluster, and other nodes will join it. If another node comes up first, it won't be able to join anything, thus you get a "broken cluster".

You can find more information on restarting the whole cluster here:
http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/restartingcluster.html

Answer (score 0):

Recommendate  way of bootstrapping cluster is to start a advanced node first then second and third  so for you need to check lsn no of all nodes or check grastate.date file where you can check all nodes value .

so follow these steps your cluster node will not be crash

Comment: Because galera cluster mechanism is that if you are initiate Galera cluster then first node should start with bootstrap (systemctl start mysql --wsrep-new-cluster )
 
 But in your case all nodes are starting normal (systemctl start mysql ) so when first node start it guess i am not bootstrap node and need to check if any donor node is available for sync up but it didn't find .
 the same thing happen with rest of the node.
 and they didn't find and donor node.                                                                                This is the main reason your cluster is failing .